# Javascript file is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, flask

The structure of my project is as following:

```
>app/
>>templates/
>>> ...my html files

>>static/
>>>css

>>>index.js
```

Here is what's inside my index.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
    $("#myTable").on('click','.btn btn-primary',function(){
         // get the current row
         var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");

         var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
         var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
         var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
         var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get current row 4th TD
         var col5=currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get current row 5th TD
         var data =col1+"\n"+col2+"\n"+col3+"\n"+col4+"\n"+col5;

         alert(data);
    });
});
```

Then I include it to my html file, like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
```

All of the above seems to have no effect when I run a local server. **Seems like .js is not being executed. What am I missing here?**

P.S I tried clearing cache, reloading the page- did not help. Checked in the console and no errors what so ever...

Comment: Could you add a console.log('before') before the ready function and 
 another console.log('after')  at the beginning of the ready function? If the before doesn't get logged it means the file is not being executed and finally another console.log('on click') at the beginning of the on click function to see where it is failing.

Comment: when you say - "Then I include it to my html file, like so:" ... is that on some top level index.html file or is it inside of some html buried in the templates folder?

Comment: @JuanV I tried adding console.log() as advised - none of those are getting logged.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, I include in my index.html (which is inside /templates folder)

Comment: I'm guessing that's the issue - I haven't used flask, but I looked around and what I found is that {{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }} basically resolves into "static/index.js" - which if being called from within another folder (templates) it can't reach the static file path.  I'd say you could make an index.html main page to load everything in, or possibly try pathing on the flask syntax (not sure if it would be valid though - somehting like: {{ url_for('../static', filename='index.js') }}). or maybe, just for POC you could put the static folder in the templates folder, just to check

Comment: Okay, so the javascript code itself is irrelevant as the file is not being loaded. I haven't used flask but according to documentation the call url_for indicates index.js should be on the static folder which seems to be the case so that's all fine. The last thing I can think to try is, check the javascript tag that's being created on the html file once you load it, most probably it's a problem of folder structure.

Comment: @Kyle I tried to do as you advised. Put my static folder inside the templates just to check. It does see the js file now, but also keeps throwing the following error: GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND). Any ideas?